# Python Web Scraping cannot extract the data and Display None

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-mining

Good day. I am hoping that somebody can help me in what I am trying to accomplish.
I wanted to scrape this page https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0x27e89d357957cE332Ff442DB69F4b476401BbBc5 but since I am new to this, its very challenging for me and have been trying this for days already. Help will be appreciated very much since this is my stepping stone to a new job.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contractpage = requests.get("https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0x27e89d357957cE332Ff442DB69F4b476401BbBc5")
ca = BeautifulSoup(contractpage.content, 'html.parser')

#printprice
price = ca.find(id='dark:text-white text-gray-800 text-sm md:text-lg')
print(price)

#24h Change
change= ca.find(id='text-sm md:text-lg dark:text-success-bright text-success-bright')
change= change.find('span', class_='dark:text-white text-gray-800 text-sm md:text-lg').get_text()
print(change)
```

When I run the script to test, it only displays None.

```
===== RESTART: C:/Python38/Temp1.py =====
None
None
>>>

Data To Be Extracted
  Price: $0.000000054851
  24h Change: 295.7%
  24h Volume: $4,488,019
  Liquidity: $3,422,055
  MarketCap: $37,890,633
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use "selenium" with beautiful soup as requests does not support dynamic pages well. Here's what I tried, and it works.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://charts.bogged.finance/?token=0x27e89d357957cE332Ff442DB69F4b476401BbBc5")
time.sleep(10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
res = soup.find('h4', class_='dark:text-white text-gray-800 text-sm md:text-lg').get_text()
print(res)
```